# subversion synchronize part of a repository

Tags: svn, synchronization

We have a repository hosted in-house and we want to synchronize some of the projects on an online repository. By looking at `svnsync` command, it seems that the synchronization is for all the repository. Is there a way to restrict the synchronization to some directories?

Comment: Items that should not be replicated, should probably be in a separate repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goal was to make my code available to the public using Google Code. Fortunately they provide a `Mercurial` repository. So I ended up mixing both `SVN` and `Mercurial`.

- Clone the project from `Google Code` on the local machine into folder `project-hg`
- Checkout the project using the in-house SVN into the folder `project-hg`
- Add and commit the files using `Mercurial` and ignore `.svn` folders
- Push the changes to `Google Code`

Every time I want to synchronize my project with `Google Code` I do

- `svn update`
- Commit the modification using `Mercurial`
- Push the changes to `Google Code`

I will lose the revision history from SVN but it’s not a problem for me.